# Will Ubuntu work on a MacBook Pro 9,2?

Tags: macbook

Does Ubuntu 15.10 or 15.04 work on a MacBook Pro 9,2, has anyone installed it successfully?

Comment: The best way to find out is to put Ubuntu on a bootable USB stick and boot off it on the target device.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unsure of dual-boot capability with OSX at the moment (however it is unlikely that OSX can't use GRUB as a bootloader) it will most definitely work with a minimum of effort. Probably the most troublesome thing you will have to deal with is getting the wireless card working, as it's an airport/bluetooth card. It may use a fully broadcomm based chipset (as I believe many apple products do, at least in their mobile space) or it may have an apple-manufactured chipset. Worst comes to worst (and this is *extremely* unlikely) you might have to throw in a new PCIe-mini card that does have available, compatible, drivers.

EDIT: According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1703667), drivers for airport cards can be obtained by installing the package `linux-firmware-nonfree`